# And we could all use a little change

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

"Sometimes, I feel like I could use some change in life."

"Prudent thought. Know, however, that to change one must first destroy."

"How am I supposed to do that?"

"Allow me to chronicle seven tales of metamorphosis. Therein, my child, you shall find enlightenment."

> 1. A **shop**, once **insufficient** (*2*,***3***) , went on **to withdraw beliefs**.
> 2. A **standard procedure** (*2*), changed an **anatomical slippage** (***1***) into **breakdown**.
> 3. An attempt **to administer** (*1*) turned **a children's book character** (***2***) into **a visitor from the unknown**.
> 4. An attempt **to tell** changed **an urban street vehicle** (*3*) into **a railway vehicle** (***3***).
> 5. **A former president** (***4***) made **garments** (*4*) into **something of no concern**.
> 6. **An Apple product** turned a **spiked club** (*4*) into **that woman** (***3***).
> 7. A **small particle** (***2***) that once **travelled by sea** is now **grinned** (*6*) at.

"That...made no sense at all."

"Patience, my child, for I am yet to narrate the greatest change of all, one that bespeaks the answer you seek."

> *????* → Spiritual energy → ***????***

"So I need spiritual energy to destroy stuff or whatever? I gotta say, that doesn't really help."

"I'm afraid, revelations must ever be enigmatic. Go seek the wisdom of the astute minds of Puzzling.SE; perhaps they can uncover the ten-letter answer."

...and here we are. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1

> STORE = S TO RE, turning S*C***A**NT to RECANT

2

> P*R*OTOCOL = PRO TO COL, turning **P**ROLAPSE into COLLAPSE

3

> *E*NFORCE = EN FOR CE, turning A**L**ICE into ALIEN

4

> INFORM = IN FOR M, turning TR*A*M to TR**A**IN

5

> CLI**N**TON = CL INTO N, turning CLO*T*HING into NOTHING

6

> MACINTOSH = MAC INTO SH, turning MAC*E* into SH**E**

7

> A**T**OM = A TO M, turning SAILED into SMILE*D*

Putting together the formatted letters yields

> *CREATED* ↦ **APLANET**

But I can't seem to find the last step(s) to get the ten-letter word required.

---

<sup>(Final part by @Bass, who tried to offer it in the comments, but got the righteous and exceedingly honourable response of getting the answer turned into a CW)</sup>

Combining the clues found in the answers with the final part of the question we get to the double length grand finale of

> Created -> Spritual energy -> A planet

Which can be resolved by something that can "destroy stuff", as hinted in the question:

> DETONATORS = "DE to NA to RS", turning MADE into MANA into MARS.

Comment: All correct so far! I'll add a hint for the last step if it sits unsolved till tomorrow.

Comment: Just in case it's helpful... rot13(Gur gvgyr vf n ylevp sebz NYY FGNE ol FZNFU ZBHGU...)

Comment: The final answer must be rot13(qrgbangbef, tvivat znqr -> znan -> znef)

Comment: @Bass that's it, nicely done!

Comment: @Bass nice! Post an answer.

Comment: Nah, you did all the hard work, I only got the tiny final part.

Comment: So I'll make this CW and you edit it in, if you please.

Comment: Well, if you insist.

Comment: Wait… so is your interlocutor advising you to take a long-distance trip, @Ankoganit ?

Comment: @msh210 That's certainly the least questionable interpretation... :)